# Overriding TabBar selectedIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a viewController that inherits from **UITabBarController** .

I am trying to override the selectedIndex variable so that I can get notified when it gets changed with the didSet like the code below.

```
override var selectedIndex: Int {
    didSet {
        refreshTabBar()
    }
}
```

The problem is that that function is not getting called when tabs get changed and I need to know why.

**PS: I do not want to call it from the didSelect delegate method.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As apple documentation says about `selectedIndex`:

> This property nominally represents an index into the array of the
>   viewControllers property.

So it's computed property which returns firstIndex of selectedViewController from viewControllers.
And on setting it changes the selectedViewController.

Use some other UITabBarController property instead. F.e:

```
override var selectedViewController: UIViewController? {
    didSet { 
        print(selectedIndex)
        refreshTabBar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `selectedIndex` programmatically to call the function

```
class FirstViewController: TabViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.selectedIndex = 1
    }


}

class TabViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override var selectedIndex: Int{
        didSet {
            refreshTabBar()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not want to subclass UITabBarController but thanks a lot :)